# Disable swipe event when using popup in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

My application has a swipeleft and swiperight feature which brings up the navigation menu. The code looks like this.

```
$(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", function(swipeEvent) {
   //my code here
}
```

In a page of the app I am using a [jquery mobile popup](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/) to display an image. The problem I have is that the swipeleft and swiperight still works inside the popup and brings up the navigation bar in the background and I dont want this.

I have used data-dismissible="false" on the popup widget but that does not help.

How do you think I should fix this problem?

Comment: Test if the popup is visible in the handler

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this stuff. What do you mean by handler? Is that the swipeleft and swipe right events? And how do I test if it is visible in the handler?

Comment: the handler is the function passed to on. To test if the popup is visible, you can use something like: $("#mypopup").is(":visible")

Comment: You bound your events on the document as a whole... Try binding it on something more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  event.stopPropagation(); worked for me.

I added swipeleft and swiperight handlers on my popup div and used event.stopPropagation(); inside it.

```
    $('#mypopup').on('swipeleft swiperight', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a function to the popupcreate event (http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#event-create) that nullifies the swipeleft swiperight functionality. One way to do this would be to have the popupcreate update a global variable to true, and then have your .on(swipeleft,swiperight) check the value of that variable before doing anything. Then you could set it to false on popupafterclose event.

Comment: Thank you Isaac. I am using requireJS to load pages so I dont think I can create a global variable.

Comment: You could try this: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/require-js-and-global-variables/